# Create a string from uint32/16_t and then parse back the original numbers

Tags: c, char, printf, scanf, uint32-t

I need to put into a char* some uint32_t and uint16_t numbers. Then I need to get them back from the buffer.

I have read some questions and I've tried to use sprintf to put them into the char* and sscanf get the original numbers again. However, I'm not able to get them correctly.

Here's an example of my code with only 2 numbers. But I need more than 2, that's why I use realloc. Also, I don't know how to use sprintf and sscanf properly with uint16_t

```
uint32_t gid = 1100;
uint32_t uid = 1000;
char* buffer = NULL;
uint32_t offset = 0;

buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
sprintf(buffer, "%d", gid);
offset += sizeof(uint32_t);

buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(buffer));
sprintf(buffer+sizeof(uint32_t), "%d", uid);

uint32_t valorGID;
uint32_t valorUID;

sscanf(buffer, "%d", &valorGID);
buffer += sizeof(uint32_t);
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &valorUID);

printf("ValorGID %d ValorUID %d \n", valorGID, valorUID);
```

And what I get is

```
ValorGID 11001000 ValorUID 1000
```

What I need to get is

```
ValorGID 1100 ValorUID 1000
```

I am new in C, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
sprintf(buffer, "%d", gid);
offset += sizeof(uint32_t);

buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(buffer));
sprintf(buffer+sizeof(uint32_t), "%d", uid);
```

This doesn't really make sense, and will not work as intended except in lucky circumstances.

Let us assume that the usual `CHAR_BIT == 8` holds, so `sizeof(uint32_t) == 4`. Further, let us assume that `int` is a signed 32-bit integer in two's complement representation without padding bits.

`sprintf(buffer, "%d", gid)` prints the decimal string representation of the bit-pattern of `gid` interpreted as an `int` to buffer. Under the above assumptions, `gid` is interpreted as a number between -2147483648 and 2147483647 inclusive. Thus the decimal string representation may contain a `'-'`, contains 1 to 10 digits and the 0-terminator, altogether it uses two to twelve bytes. But you have allocated only four bytes, so whenever `999 < gid < 2^32-99` (the signed two's complement interpretation is `> 999` or `< -99`), `sprintf` writes past the allocated buffer size.

That is undefined behaviour.

It's likely to not crash immediately because allocating four bytes usually gives you a larger chunk of memory effectively (if e.g. `malloc` always returns 16-byte aligned blocks, the twelve bytes directly behind the allocated four cannot be used by other parts of the programme, but belong to the programme's address space, and writing to them will probably go undetected). But it can easily crash later when the end of the allocated chunk lies on a page boundary.

Also, since you advance the write offset by four bytes for subsequent `sprintf`s, part of the previous number gets overwritten if the string representation (excluding the 0-termnator) used more than four bytes (while the programme didn't yet crash due to writing to non-allocated memory).

The line

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(buffer));
```

contains further errors.

1. `buffer = realloc(buffer, new_size);` loses the reference to the allocated memory and causes a leak if `realloc` fails. Use a temporary and check for success

   ```
   char *temp = realloc(buffer, new_size);
   if (temp == NULL) {
       /* reallocation failed, recover or cleanup */
       free(buffer);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   /* it worked */
   buffer = temp;
   /* temp = NULL; or let temp go out of scope */
   ```
2. The new size `sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(buffer)` of the new allocation is always the same, `sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(char*)`. That's typically eight or twelve bytes, so it doesn't take many numbers to write outside the allocated area and cause a crash or memory corruption (which may cause a crash much later).

You **must** keep track of the number of bytes allocated to `buffer` and use that to calculate the new size. There is no (portable¹) way to determine the size of the allocated memory block from the pointer to its start.

---

Now the question is whether you want to store the string representations or the bit patterns in the buffer.

Storing the string representations has the problem that the length of the string representation varies with the value. So you need to include separators between the representations of the numbers, or ensure that all representations have the same length by padding (with spaces or leading zeros) if necessary. That would for example work like

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#define MAKESTR(x) # x
#define STR(x) MAKESTR(x)

/* A uint32_t can use 10 decimal digits, so let each field be 10 chars wide */
#define FIELD_WIDTH 10

uint32_t gid = 1100;
uint32_t uid = 1000;

size_t buf_size = 0, offset = 0;
char *buffer = NULL, *temp = NULL;
buffer = realloc(buffer, FIELD_WIDTH + 1); /* one for the '\0' */
if (buffer == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
buf_size = FIELD_WIDTH + 1;
sprintf(buffer, "%0" STR(FIELD_WIDTH) PRIu32, gid);
offset += FIELD_WIDTH;

temp = realloc(buffer, buf_size + FIELD_WIDTH);
if (temp == NULL) {
    free(buffer);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
buffer = temp;
temp = NULL;
buf_size += FIELD_WIDTH;
sprintf(buffer + offset, "%0" STR(FIELD_WIDTH) PRIu32, uid);
offset += FIELD_WIDTH;
/* more */

uint32_t valorGID;
uint32_t valorUID;

/* rewind for scanning */
offset = 0;

sscanf(buffer + offset, "%" STR(FIELD_WIDTH) SCNu32, &valorGID);
offset += FIELD_WIDTH;
sscanf(buffer + offset, "%" STR(FIELD_WIDTH) SCNu32, &valorUID);

printf("ValorGID %u ValorUID %u \n", valorGID, valorUID);
```

with zero-padded fixed-width fields. If you'd rather use separators than a fixed width, the calculation of the required length and the offsets becomes more complicated, but unless the numbers are large, it would use less space.

If you'd rather store the bit-patterns, which would be the most compact way of storing, you'd use something like

```
size_t buf_size = 0, offset = 0;
unsigned char *buffer = NULL, temp = NULL;
buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
if (buffer == NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
buf_size = sizeof(uint32_t);
for(size_t b = 0; b < sizeof(uint32_t); ++b) {
    buffer[offset + b] = (gid >> b*8) & 0xFF;
}
offset += sizeof(uint32_t);

temp = realloc(buffer, buf_size + sizeof(uint32_t));
if (temp == NULL) {
    free(buffer);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
buffer = temp;
temp = NULL;
buf_size += sizeof(uint32_t);
for(size_t b = 0; b < sizeof(uint32_t); ++b) {
    buffer[offset + b] = (uid >> b*8) & 0xFF;
}
offset += sizeof(uint32_t);

/* And for reading the values */
uint32_t valorGID, valorUID;

/* rewind */
offset = 0;
valorGID = 0;
for(size_t b = 0; b < sizeof(uint32_t); ++b) {
    valorGID |= buffer[offset + b] << b*8;
}
offset += sizeof(uint32_t);
valorUID = 0;
for(size_t b = 0; b < sizeof(uint32_t); ++b) {
    valorUID |= buffer[offset + b] << b*8;
}
offset += sizeof(uint32_t);
```

---

¹ If you know how `malloc` etc. work in your implementation, it may be possible to find the size from `malloc`'s bookkeeping data.

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback. As I said, I'm new in C. I didn't know I must check if realloc fails. 
The first solution, string representation, is what I need. 
I will implement it. 
Again, thank you for your time!

Comment: You're welcome. I hope you hadn't got the impression I was chastising you, the point is just that in C the programmer has to do the error checking, no nice exceptions that tell you exactly what went wrong on which line of code. Of course, checking for failure of `malloc/realloc` has a good chance of never detecting a failure. But for the one time it does, you'll be happy to have it.

Answer (score 1):

The format specifier `'%d'` is for `int` and thus is wrong for `uint32_t`. First `uint32_t` is an unsigned type, so you should at least use `'%u'`, but then it might also have a different width than `int` or `unsigned`. There are macros foreseen in the standard: `PRIu32` for `printf` and `SCNu32` for `scanf`. As an example:

```
sprintf(buffer, "%" PRIu32, gid);
```

Comment: May I use that macro for printing and other functions too? Thank You!

Comment: Sure, and there is a whole bunch of analogous macros for the other types and specifiers.

Answer (score 1):

The representation returned by sprintf is a char*. If you are trying to store an array of integers as their string representatins then your fundamental data type is a char**. This is a ragged matrix of char if we are storing only the string data itself, but since the longest string a `uint32_t` can yield is 10 chars, plus one for the terminating null, it makes sense to preallocate this many bytes to hold each string.

So to store n uint32_t's from array a in array s as strings:

```
const size_t kMaxIntLen=11;

uint32_t *a,b;
// fill a somehow
...

size_t n,i;
char **s.*d;

if((d=(char*)malloc(n*kMaxIntLen))==NULL)
   // error!
if((s=(char**)malloc(n*sizeof(char*)))==NULL)
   // error!
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    s[i]=d+i; // this is incremented by sizeof(char*) each iteration
    snprintf(s[i],kMaxIntLen,"%u",a[i]); // snprintf to be safe
    }
```

Now the ith number is at s[i] so to print it is just `printf("%s",s[i]);`, and to retrieve it as an integer into `b` is `sscanf(s[i],"%u",&b);`.

Subsequent memory management is a bit trickier. Rather than constantly using using `realloc()` to grow the buffer, it is better to preallocate a chunk of memory and only alter it when exhausted. If `realloc()` fails it returns `NULL`, so store a pointer to your main buffer before calling it and that way you won't lose a reference to your data. Reallocate the `d` buffer first - again allocate enough room for several more strings - then if it succeeds see if `d` has changed. If so, destroy (`free()`) the `s` buffer, `malloc()` it again and rebuild the indices (you have to do this since if `d` has changed all your indices are stale). If not, `realloc()` `s` and fix up the new indices. I would suggest wrapping this whole thing in a structure and having a set of routines to operate on it, e.g.:

```
typedef struct StringArray
{
char **strArray;
char *data;
size_t nStrings;
} StringArray;
```

This is a lot of work. Do you *have* to use C? This is vastly easier as a C++ STL `vector<string>` or `list<string>` with the `istringstream` classes and the `push_back()` container method.

Comment: Yes, I'm writting a software to do operation in an ext2 FS, as a practice for college. And this is the first time we use C.

Answer (score 0):

```
uint32_t gid = 1100;
uint32_t uid = 1000;
char* buffer = NULL;
uint32_t offset = 0;

buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t));
sprintf(buffer, "%d", gid);
offset += sizeof(uint32_t);

buffer = realloc(buffer, sizeof(uint32_t) + sizeof(buffer));
sprintf(buffer+sizeof(uint32_t), "%d", uid);

uint32_t valorGID;
uint32_t valorUID;

sscanf(buffer, "%4d", &valorGID);
buffer += sizeof(uint32_t);
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &valorUID);

printf("ValorGID %d ValorUID %d \n", valorGID, valorUID);
```

`

I think this may resolve the issue !

Comment: Yes, but I need to add more than 1 number. And sometimes with more than 4 digits.